# trigger parameterized build doesnt find buildpath in jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

My code dynamically creates a `.groovy` file which triggers parameterized build inside a parallel step:

```
def executeParallelBuilds(){
    try {
        parallel(
            build1BUILD: {
                def build1BUILD = build job: 'TA/test1', parameters: [string(name: "CPNUM_PARAM", value: 1.141)]
            }, 
            build2BUILD: {
                def build2BUILD = build job: 'TA/test2', parameters: [string(name: "CPNUM_PARAM", value: 1.141)]
            },
            failFast: false
        )
    } catch (e) {
        echo "An error ocurred while building"
        currentBuild.result="UNSTABLE"
    }
}
return this;
```

Now, I load and execute the groovy file with:

```
node('master'){
    def executeGroovyFile = load buildFilePath
    executeGroovyFile.executeParallelBuilds()
}
```

But it seems that my pipeline cant find the `Buildjobs` by path.

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] node
Running on master in C:\DevApps\Jenkins\workspace\TA\pipeline_1.0_TEMPLATE
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] load
[Pipeline] { (D:\BuildResults_tmp\TA\MBE3\\buildString.groovy)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // load
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [build1BUILD] { (Branch: build1BUILD)
[Pipeline] [build2BUILD] { (Branch: build2BUILD)
[Pipeline] [build1BUILD] build
[Pipeline] [build1BUILD] }
[build1BUILD] Failed in branch build1BUILD
[Pipeline] [build2BUILD] build
[Pipeline] [build2BUILD] }
[build2BUILD] Failed in branch build2BUILD
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] echo
An error ocurred while building
[Pipeline] }
```

What am I doing wrong? I load and execute the `.groovy` file on my master so that the pipeline should be able to find the other jobs. (Without node declaration I am not able to load and execute)

EDIT: What confuses me is, that I don't get the following error:

> No parameterized job named some-downtream-job-name found

Comment: i think all we can see from what you have provided is that both child jobs are failing. any idea why? why are you confused that you don't get "No parameterized job named some-downtream-job-name found". you must have some additional information that's not in the question? :)

Comment: The problem is, (like you can see in the output) that none of the branches are able to find the jobs that they have to trigger `[Pipeline] [build1BUILD] build` . At this point the desired job should be printed. Like:  `[Pipeline] [build1BUILD] build TA/test1` - both child jobs didnt even start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the build call. 
I saved the whole code as String to a `.groovy` file. This gave me some struggling with the right notation. (quotes and double qoutes) 
After calling my script as:

```
def build1BUILD = build job: BuildJobNameList[i], parameters: [string(name: "CPNUM_PARAM", value: 1.141)]
```

everything works fine

Comment: You should mark your own answer as accepted if it solved your issue - so that others can see that your issue has been resolved

Comment: I have to wait till tomorrow ;)